# Rate limit for basic phone number lookup

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

What's the rate limit for the free basic phone number lookup? Is it different for paid accounts? Is it correct to expect error code `60616` instead of `20429`?

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing this on an inbound call, there is no rate limit - each lookup from an inbound call will succeed.

If you are using the REST API to do the lookup, when you exceed the rate limit the exception or headers that are returned will have helpful information. For example, I am using the [Polly library](https://www.thepollyproject.org/) to watch for rate limit exceeded events and then retry.

The Twilio docs say to check the REST API documentation for the specific product limits. Neither the Lookup v1 or v2 docs list a limit.

The error code that you included indicates it might be a downstream resource that is causing the limit. However this page about "[add-ons](https://www.twilio.com/docs/add-ons/support)" says that error code is Twilio's responsibility - so you could open a support ticket.

Based on other documentation, Twilio has per minute, per resource, per hour, and per day limits on the various products.If it was me, I'd do an experiment of limiting my requests to 60 per second and then either increase or decrease the amount.

Here are some resources to explore:
[Twilio Error Code Dictionary for ERROR - 60616:](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/60616#error-60616)

> **Lookup rate limit exceeded** - The rate of lookup requests exceeds
> allowable limits for the requested package.
>
> **Possible Causes** - Your application is making lookups at a rate higher
> than allowed for the requested package. This may be intentional or the
> result of an unexpected condition in your code.
>
> **Possible Solutions** - Our downstream providers do not have uniform rate
> limits. Confirm the published rate limits for the requested package
> and debug your application to ensure your lookup request rate remains
> under allowed limits.

[Monitor your usage](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/rest-api-best-practices#monitor-your-usage):

> Twilio strongly encourages all developers to monitor API response
> headers, in particular these two:
>
> Twilio-Concurrent-Requests: 1
> Twilio-Request-Duration: 0.111
>
> Twilio-Concurrent-Requests indicates the number of concurrent
> requests, at that moment, for the account. Subaccount requests do not
> roll up into master account requests. The concurrency count includes
> requests that receive a 429 response.
>
> Twilio-Request-Duration is the time it took for the request to
> complete within the Twilio platform. This is the period between when
> the request hit our edge and when the response was sent back to your
> server. This does not include the network time between Twilio servers
> and your servers.